# Changing default directory in Quickly

Tags: quickly

I'm unhappy with the fact that Quickly creates all my new projects in my Home directory. I figured it would be something in create.py in the template's folder, but I'm new enough to Python and Quickly that I can't figure it out. I'm sure this is an easy answer, how do I change the directory where Quickly creates new folders?

Answer (score 1):

Quickly will create a folder wherever you invoke it from. Just make sure you change the current directory to the location where you want it to create the folder containing your new app first, and then run the `quickly create` command.

So for example, if you want to create a test app that you're not going to keep in the `/tmp` folder, you can run it with:

```
cd /tmp
quickly create ubuntu-application TestApp
```

Then Quickly will create the app under `/tmp/testapp`